# URL that automatically opens popup on page

Tags: jquery, css, html

Site: http://bit.ly/1dPAXsS

The above webpage opens a popup when the "Inform me when available" button is clicked. Using the current HTML I believe clicking the class "open" triggers the popup:

```
<a href="#" class="open cc-inform"><img src="http://uat.priworks.com/SustainGreen/sites/all/themes/sustaingreen/images/cc-applynow.png"></a>
```

My question is, can I formulate a URL that when loaded automatically triggers the popup to open. It should NOT open anytime the page is loaded but only when coming from a page using a specific url with the trigger. ie.e www.site.com/page#open or something - Pretty sure I can do this with js/jquery but not sure if I will need to change the way the popup is currently.

Comment: Automatic pop-ups differ from user-initiated pop-ups, and are generally blocked by the browser. Why do you need this?

Comment: buttons in the footer throughout the site say "keep me informed" - If on another page I would like clicking on that footer to go to the Credit page with popup auto opening. Alternative would be a global popup?

Comment: Auto pop-ups are very bad design pattern! Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Kevin but seems you are not understanding DOM concepts correctly.
The "open" class might be used to select the element and assign a click event to it, but it does not triggers the popup.
You sure can do what you need and it's easy to.

URL:

```
www.site.com/page#open
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
  if(location.hash == '#open'){
    $('.popbox .open').click()
  }
});
```